# My R shiny app works locally fine, but fails whenever I deploy due to server connection error

Tags: mysql, r, deployment, server, shiny

First of all, I have an error like below(by showLogs()):

2017-01-29T10:23:14.923154+00:00 shinyapps[153694]: Warning: Error in .local: Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

The case is that my shiny app works fine locally, but fails when deployed.
I have no idea why this happens.. (maybe the data I'm trying to load is too large, or there might be an unknown issue on my server side..)
I connect to db by dbConnect() method, but I don't think this is because of my script.

Please help me!!

Comment: Are your remote credentials correct?

Comment: What do you mean by remote credentials?

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL from the command line on the deployment machine?  If you can't, then forget about your app being able to do it.

Comment: in my Rstudio console line, I can connect to MySQL only by running the connection part of the script.

Comment: what library are you using to connect to MySQL?

Comment: library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(pool)
library(dplyr)
library(dtplyr)
I load these guys and my script looks like:
conn <- dbConnect(drv = RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname='', host='', username='', password='', port='')